# process a page on UnLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need for a php file to process when the user click a link/go back/exits a page. Its part of a saving user info process. if i do a jquery unload how would I fire the php file to load and process.

jQuery(window).bind("unload", function() {
    // what should i add?
});

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser, php runs on the server (unless you are running node.js or something but not i suspect in this case) so the javascript would need to talk to something, think ajax, to trigger something on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(':input',document.myForm).bind("change", function() { 
       setConfirmUnload(true); 
    }); // Prevent accidental navigation away
});

function setConfirmUnload(on) {
     // To avoid IE7 and prior jQuery version issues   
     // we are directly using window.onbeforeunload event
     window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
}

function unloadMessage() {

    if(Confirm('You have entered new data on this page.  If you navigate away from this page without first saving your data, the changes will be lost.')) {

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "some.php",
               data: "name=John&location=Boston",
               success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
             });

    }

}
```

Make sure you have upgraded version of jQuery. jQuery version 1.3.2 had a bug:

[Ticket #4418: beforeunload doenst work correctly](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4418)

Or use native function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `beforeunload` event. You can fire a **synchronised** ajax request in there.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
   $.ajax({
       url:    'foo',
       async:  false,
       // ...
   });
});
```

Be aware that `onbeforeunload` is not supported by some older browsers. Even if this technique works, I'm not sure how long you can (should?) block this event. Would be a pretty bad user experience if that request would block a few seconds.

A good trade-off is probably to tell the user that something has changed what was not saved yet. Do this with a few boolean checks and finally return a `string value` in the `onbeforeunload` request. The browser will then gracefully ask the user if he really wants to leave your site, also showing the string you provided.

Comment: so i could do something like url: '/files/save.php'.. would i need any other coding?

Comment: @acctman: yes, but you should add the `data` attribute ti actuall transfer some date right. Anyways, after thinking about it this is probably not a good way. I extended my answer with a more convenient way, by asking gracefully.

Comment: ok i think you lost me. what's the easiest way for a javascript newb like myself to implement. one that would be reliable, my php file is ready to go just need for it to be processed, just need a quick way of calling it up. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a synchronous AJAX call might work.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: '/foo/',
    success: function(data) { 
        // Finished.
    }
});
```

Of course, keep in mind there's no guarantee any of this will ever happen. My browser may crash. My computer may even power down. And of course I may disable JavaScript. So you'll definitely need a server-side way of handling this in case the convenient JavaScript technique doesn't actually work.